# Projected gradient descent with matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, gradient-descent, projection

I have a scalar function $f(\rho) = Tr(\rho H) + c\ Tr(\rho\log\rho)$, where $Tr$ is trace, $\rho$ is a positive semidefinite matrix with trace 1 and $H$ is a Hermitian matrix and $c$ is a postive constant and we are using the matrix logarithm.

I'm trying to minimize $f$ over all PSD $\rho$ with unit trace and would like to use gradient descent. Because I know my solution $\rho$ must have trace 1 and be positive semidefinite, I will project at each iteration onto the PSD with trace 1 subspace.

Currently, what I have tried does not work - I'm getting the wrong answer. The possibilities are

1. My gradient is incorrect. I am using $Tr(H) + T\ Tr(\log\rho)$ as the gradient. I derive this by assuming $Tr(d\rho) = 0$ so I can do it as if $\rho$ and $d\rho$ commute.
2. The projection I'm using is flawed. I am symmetrizing $\rho$ at each step using $\rho = \rho + \rho^\dagger$. I'm not sure how to project onto the positive semidefinite matrices though since $\rho$ is sometimes singular and I can't do $\rho = \sqrt{\rho^\dagger\rho}$ according to MATLAB. To keep the trace 1, I would take $\rho = \frac{\rho}{Tr(\rho)}$ within each step.

Can anyone point out how to approach this problem? Thank you.

Comment: What is $\log \rho$? Is it defined for any PSD matrix $\rho$?

Comment: @Bertrand, yes it is defined in the following way. If a matrix is PSD, it can be diagonalized. Then take the logarithm of the diagonal entries. More details here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix

Comment: Rather than the projection you have chosen, you could make use of the natural Riemannian geometry on the manifold of positive semidefinite matrices to use the adapted gradient descent algorithm in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.5280

Comment: @user1936752, few not fully unrelated comments. (i) Problems may occur with $\log \rho$ if eigenvalues are equal to zero. (ii) I am not sure that Gauss-Newton iterations are helpful because the partial derivatives may not be zero at the minimum of $f$, using Nelder-Mead may be helpful. (iii) If $\rho$ is symmetric you could simplify and replace $Tr(\rho H)$ by $Tr(\Lambda H)$ with $\Lambda$ denoting the matrix of eigenvalues of $\rho$. Similarly $Tr(\rho \log \rho) = Tr(\Lambda \log \Lambda )$. This reparameterization allows minimizing $f$ over fewer parameters $\lambda$.

Comment: @user1936752. A one penny conjecture: a minimum is achieved for $\lambda_i \rightarrow 0, \forall i \neq K$ and $\lambda_K \rightarrow 1$ where $\lambda_K$ is the eigenvalue multiplied with the smallest diagonal element of $H$.

Answer (score 1):

The feasible set in your optimization problem (positive semidefinite matrices of unit trace) is called the **spectrahedron**.

The most popular projected-gradient like algorithms for minimizing a function over the spectrahedron are specializations of the [Frank-Wolfe algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank%E2%80%93Wolfe_algorithm). See for example the paper *Sparse Approximate Solutions to Semidefinite Programs* by Elad Hazan [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-78773-0_27). The paper is well-cited, and many of the papers that cite it expand upon its original idea.